# How to retrieve all rows from column 'rec_host' that equal 1 and also 0 for echoing

Tags: mysql

I want to know how to make a prepared statement query that SELECTS all `rec_host` rows and counts all the ones that equal 1, and all the ones that equal 0, so that I can print them out separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
SELECT IF(rec_host=0,0,1) as value, COUNT(rec_host)
FROM lhr_reviews
GROUP BY value
```

Try it! :)

Explanation:

- It Checks if `rec_host` is equal to `0`. If it is equal, the value will be `0`, otherwise `1`.
- All the fields with the same value are grouped
- `COUNT` will count all the rows which are in each group.

Comment: that seems to be what i need, but what am I doing wrong here?  SELECT `host_name`, IF(`rec_host` = 1) AS cnt1, IF(`rec_host` = 0) AS cnt2, COUNT(cnt1) COUNT(cnt2)
                              FROM `lhr_reviews` 
                              ORDER BY 
                              `rank_total` DESC 
                              LIMIT 10

Comment: The IF sentence is not correct. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

try this::

```
SELECT rec_host as value, COUNT(rec_host)
FROM table_name
where rec_host in (0,1)
GROUP BY value
```